# ActiveModel include_root_in_json

Tags: ruby, activemodel

I am a bit confused by this option... which can be found in the example below

```
 user = User.find(1)
  user.as_json
  # => { "user": {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
                  "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true} }

  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
  user.as_json
  # => {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
        "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true}
```

http://rubydoc.info/gems/activemodel/3.1.3/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON

Why does ActiveModel require you to use ActiveRecord to tell it that you dont want base objects in the root of your serialized objects?

I cannot seem to get this to work, currently I am doing:

```
require "active_model"
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

But it just says that it cannot find the constant "ActiveRecord", which makes sense, but is this just a typo in the docs or is there some real reason for this? as ActiveRecord seems to deal with data storage concerns, ActiveModel seems to deal with augmenting simple models...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... [Rails source for active model](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb) has the same example.
Where are you trying to use it? In my ActiveModels I normally do:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  # ... more includes

  self.include_root_in_json = false

  # ... model stuff
end
```

Comment: I didn't think you could set it per model, as there was a question around that somewhere on stackoverflow. I am currently using the ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON like you are within my model, and setting the include_root_in_json at root level within the boot.rb as *apparently* you can only set it for all or nothing.